# SQL Server Merge Replication - No subscription is on this publication or article

Tags: sql-server, replication, merge-replication, sql-server-2022

I have setup a merge replication publication and added a subscriber but when I view the synchronization status I just get the error message: "No subscription is on this publication or article".

Looking through replication monitor shows this as an Error 14050 but I haven't been able to find much detail on why this is happening. I had the same tables replicating using transactional replication without any issues, but need to use merge since the subscriber gets updates that need to push back to the publisher.

I have tried turning on verbose logging but it's not writing a log so I can't tell what's happening. I have also tried deleting and rebuilding both the publication and subscription but continue to get the same message.

What do I need to do to resolve this? Thanks

Comment: Did you remove that article from your Transactional Replication topology before adding it to a Merge Replication topology?

Comment: @J.D. Initially I left the Transactional and created the Merge but after receiving this error the first time I deleted all of the publications and recreated the Merge.